# How to iterate over objects contained in some other structure and call their methods (make them known to Cython)?

Tags: cython

Methods go unrecognized when I iterate over objects of the same type (or of derived class) and call the same method within a loop.

This happens when I iterate over objects stored in a data structure (in this case, `collections.OrderedDict`) within a class I've defined. I've made the methods available to Cython in a `pxd` file.

This happens whether or not `MyClass` is a base class or derived class.

I'm using `unittest` to test my code.

I'm wondering if Cython doesn't support this or if some information about an object is missing when it's a Cython extension.

**myclass.pxd**

```
cdef class MyClass():
    cdef public object _dict
    cdef void add_obj(self, name, obj)
    cdef void m(self)
    cdef void _m(self)
```

**myclass.pyx**

```
from collections import OrderedDict
cdef class MyClass():
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._dict = OrderedDict()

    cdef void add_obj(self, name, obj):
        self._dict[name] = obj 

    cdef void m(self):
        # user defines this in derived class
        pass

    cdef void _m(self):
        cdef int i = 0
        print('running user defined method')
        self.m()
        print(self._dict.keys())
        print('adding objects')
        for key, obj in self._dict.items():
            # ERROR
            print('obj')
            print(obj)
            obj.m()
            i += 1
            print('added an object')
            print(i)
```

**test.pyx**

```
from mypkg.core.myclass cimport MyClass
import unittest

cdef class ChildClass(MyClass):
    cdef void m(self):
        self.add_obj('a', MyClass())
        self.add_obj('b', MyClass())
        self.add_obj('c', MyClass())

cdef class ParentClass(MyClass):
    cdef void m(self):
        self.add_obj('a', ChildClass())
        self.add_obj('b', ChildClass())
        self.add_obj('c', ChildClass())

cdef ParentClass H = ParentClass()

class SetupTree(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        H._m()

    def test_tree(self):
        print(H._dict)
        print(len(H._dict))
```

**Output**

```
running user defined method
odict_keys(['a', 'b', 'c'])
adding objects
obj
<mypkg.test.test_system2.ChildClass object at 0x7f86ff915b38>
AttributeError: 'mypkg.test.test_system2.ChildClass' object has no attribute 'm'
Exception ignored in: 'mypkg.core.group.MyClass._m'
AttributeError: 'mypkg.test.test_system2.ChildClass' object has no attribute 'm'
OrderedDict([('a', <mypkg.test.test_system2.ChildClass object at 0x7f86ff915b38>), ('b', <mypkg.test.test_system2.ChildClass object at 0x7f86ff915d30>), ('c', <mypkg.test.test_system2.ChildClass object at 0x7f86ff915c88>)])
3
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Answer (score 0):

`cdef` methods can only be called if they can be found at compile time - they can't be looked up as Python attributes at runtime. You've done nothing in `_m` to tell Cython that `obj` is a `MyClass`, so it does not know of the existence of the `cdef` method.

You have two options:

1. Change the `cdef m(...)` to `def` (or `cpdef`) so it can be found by Python at runtime.
2. Tell Cython that `obj` is an instance of `MyClass`:

   ```
   cdef MyClass obj # you'll receive an TypeError exception if you ever 
        # attempt to assign something that isn't a MyClass to obj
   for key, obj in self._dict.items():
       obj.m() # now works!
   ```

Comment: Wow, I was thinking Cython would automatically infer that when converting to C code the way a compiler can when compiling C++. Thanks for that.

Comment: It doesn't have the information to infer it. `obj` is coming from a dictionary which could hold any Python object. This is somewhere where the static typing that Cython does and the dynamic typing that Python does often causes confusion -  Cython can't give you any error message when you compile because you _could_ mean "look for a Python function called `m` at runtime".